# xrandr --listproviders not showing any graphics cards

Tags: x11, xorg, nvidia, xrandr, wayland

I would like to be able to have `xrandr` recognize my two RTX 3070 Nvidia Graphics Cards.

However, xrandr does not return anything.

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 0
```

I am using `nvidia-prime` and `nvidia-driver-530`.

I believe that this is caused by `Xwayland` running an X composition layer on top of `wayland` and not running `xorg` directly.

Although I don't really know if `wayland` is actually the root cause, I believe I would like to disable all `wayland` on my server machine (Ubuntu Server 22.04) and run `xorg` only. I am accessing the server through `ssh -X` from a Ubuntu desktop client.

```
xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*XWAYLAND15 3840/620x2160/330+0+0  XWAYLAND15
```

```
xinput
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
tty
```

```
loginctl show-session 1 -p Type
Type=tty
```

What settings or configuration would I need to get `xrandr --listproviders` to display the Nvidia graphics cards?

I would be happy to provide additional details as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, what I was trying to do did not seem possible.

Since I do not think the graphics software is meant to be run this way on a headless Ubuntu server, I installed `lightdm` so I could access a GUI on the server machine and connect it directly to the monitor with a direct video connection.

With the GUI installed, everything seemed to work fine with all the Nvidia cards being recognized.